# How to verify in my Ubuntu am i using opensource video codec's or not?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, video, video-editor

I am using H.264 video codec in my Ubuntu for video editing. But how do i verify it is the openSource H.264? apt-get install x264 i applied, does it installs the Free H.264 or commercial one?.

hints: http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the page you've linked to says it all:

"x264 is a free software library and application for encoding video streams into the H.264/MPEG-4 AVC format, and is released under the terms of the GNU GPL.

Another indicator, x264 is in Universe, which is free, community maintained software. It looks like there is a non-free counterpart, h264enc, in Multiverse.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/x264
http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/h264enc

Comment: But wiki is confusing me http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X264 (the last paragraph).

Comment: The last paragraph talks about a possible patent controversy, but the patent seems to have a later date, which should make x264 prior art. Anyway, if you are having doubts about x264, why not use another codec? Theora, anyone?

Comment: There is no another codec really similar to x264 for 1080p + speed + quality. Theroa and dirac and other all i used.